# Insert Data into SQL Table from an Excel Sheet

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

if I have the following table in SQL,

```
Item  Desc   Type   Location    Quantity    Unit_Price

A     AAA     X        1           0          20.00
B     BBB     Y        2           0          10.00
B     CCC     X        2           0          50.00
C     DDD     Z        1           0         150.00
C     EEE     Y        3           0          70.00
D     FFF     Z        3           0          65.00
```

And the following Excel Sheet

```
Item    Location   Quantity
A          1           1
B          1           2
B          2           3
C          1          40
C          3         500
D          3          10
```

How do I insert these quantities in to the SQL table reading from my Excel table ?

Answer (score 3):

To do this with T-SQL, you can follow this [tutorial](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-using-tsql-to-import-excel-data-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/) in detail and start by pulling the data into a temporary table, as shown in the following `SELECT…INTO` statement:

```
SELECT * INTO #ProductInfo
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES; IMEX=1;
   Database=C:\DataFiles\ProductData.xlsx',
   [vProduct$]);
```

Using the [`OPENROWSET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190312.aspx) in-build function to retrieve Excel data where the first argument is the name of the provider which can be one of two providers:

- Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0: Use on SQL Server 32-bit editions for Excel
  2003 files (or earlier).
- Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0: Use on SQL Server
  32-bit editions for Excel 2007 files (or later) or on SQL Server
  64-bit editions for any Excel files.

The second `OPENROWSET` argument defines the provider string delimited by a semi-colon with the first part specifying the file type:

- For Excel ’97-2003 (.xls) files, use Excel 8.0.
- For Excel 2007-2010 (.xlsx) files, use Excel 12.0 Xml.
- For Excel 2007-2010 macro-enabled (.xlsm) files, use Excel 12.0
  Macro.
- For Excel 2007-2010 non-XML binary (.xlsb) files, use Excel 12.0.

The second part of the argument specifies the file’s path and file name. The third argument is the name of the spreadsheet we want to access with the dollar sign ($) appended and enclosed in brackets, as in [Products$], for example.

Once you have the data into the temporary table `#ProductInfo`, you can then convert, filter the data as necessary using an inner join and then update the Quantity field:

```
UPDATE
    p
SET
    p.Quantity = temp.Quantity
FROM dbo.Product AS p
INNER JOIN #ProductInfo AS temp
   ON temp.Item = p.Item
   AND temp.Location = p.Location;
```

Answer (score 3):

Right Click on Database -> Tasks -> Import data -> wizard will open
[image]

click on Next(Source wizard will open) and choose the "Microsoft Excel" option in DataSource dropdown and choose the excel path Click the "Next" button(Excel column and Table column should be same otherwise it won't insert).

[image]

enter destination  details in the wizard,click on Next

[image]

click the Next button
[image]

[image]

Click the Next button and Finish
[image]

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Management Studio can do this via its Import / Export features. I do this routinely using SSMS.

In SSMS, right click on your database, then choose Tasks | Import Data.

Comment: it takes me to Create Excel table in to SQL as a new table?

Comment: You can also choose to import you Excel data into an existing table. Just specify the table you want to import into.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to import the Excel sheet into your database. Then Use a query to update your table.

Comment: by creating new table?

Comment: Yes. Import you Excel Sheet into a new table. Then use a query to update your real table. Something like this: UPDATE T1 Set T1.Quantity=Te.Quantity FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN TableExcel TE on TE.Item=T1.Ítem and TE.Location=T1.Location

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx)

First import the data from excel to a temporary table (It will create new table, which you can drop later)

Once you have the data in a table, then you can update your existing one

[Here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/) is a simple step by step approach

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
Option Explicit
Public CN As ADODB.Connection
Dim Cod_Prod, Nombre, Existencia
Dim Fila, Final As Integer

Function Connect(Server As String, User As String, Pass As String, Database As String) As Boolean
 
    Set CN = New ADODB.Connection
    On Error Resume Next
 
    With CN
        
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
                            "Password=" & Pass & ";" & _
                            "Persist Security Info=True;" & _
                            "User ID=" & User & ";" & _
                            "Initial Catalog=" & Database & ";" & _
                            "Data Source=" & Server
        
        .Open
    End With
    
    If CN.State = 0 Then
        Connect = False
    Else
        Connect = True
    End If
 
End Function
Function Query()
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Field As ADODB.Field
 
    Dim Col As Long
 
    
    Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
    
Final = GetUltimoR(Hoja1)

For Fila = 2 To Final
    Cod_Prod = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 2)
    Nombre = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 3)
    Existencia = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 4)

 
    
    SQL = "insert into productos values('" & Cod_Prod & "','" & Nombre & "'," & Existencia & ");"
    RS.Open SQL, CN
Next
    
    
    RS.Open "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS", CN

 
    If RS.State Then
        Col = 1
    
        For Each Field In RS.Fields
            Cells(1, Col) = Field.Name
            Col = Col + 1
        Next Field
    
        Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset RS
        Set RS = Nothing
    End If
End Function
Function Disconnect()
    CN.Close
End Function
Public Sub run()
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim Connected As Boolean
    
    

    Connected = Connect("192.168.0.12", "usuario1", "12345", "inventario")
 
    If Connected Then

        Call Query
        Call Disconnect
    Else

        MsgBox "No podemos Conectarnos!"
    End If
End Sub


Public Function GetUltimoR(Hoja As Worksheet) As Integer
    GetUltimoR = GetNuevoR(Hoja) - 1
End Function

Public Function GetNuevoR(Hoja As Worksheet) As Integer
    
    Dim Fila As Integer
    Fila = 2
    
    Do While Hoja.Cells(Fila, 2) <> ""
        Fila = Fila + 1
    Loop
    
    GetNuevoR = Fila
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  BULK INSERT [Trading].[dbo].[tmp_mst_bhavcopy]
     FROM   'E:\Text\bhavcopy.csv' 
     WITH (
              FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
              ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',
              firstrow=2
           )
```

Comment: This will work when you will keep the excel file into the same server where your database belongs..